# Unable to type in second Telerik RadComboBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a page with five RadComboBoxes on them. When the page loads I am able to click inside any of them which begins to search the contents of the combo box.

If I select an option from the dropdown list (regardless of whether or not I narrow the search by typing), I am left unable to type within one of the other four RadComboBoxes unless I click out of the box and back in again - I can however select an item from the dropdown as usual.

Alternatively, if type in the first box without actually selecting an item, and then click in another RadComboBox I am able to type to search.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddApplicant" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                                DataTextField="Clinicians"
                                MaxHeight="180px" Filter="Contains" DataValueField="ClinicianID" HighlightTemplatedItems="True"
                                Width="350px" EmptyMessage="Search By Clinician Name"
                                ItemsPerRequest="10" DropDownWidth="350px"
                                AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="False" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: Any JS errors? By chance, is an AJAX request running when you focus/select/type into the first combo so it may be disposing the second combo which will make it lose focus? Can you paste a snippet where we can see this?